# Cleaning up validation logic

Tags: angularjs

I've just got validation working the way I want with the following code:

```html
<div class="control-group" ng-class="{ error : (submitted || accountForm.name.$dirty) && accountForm.name.$invalid }">
   <label for="name" class="control-label">Company Name:</label>
   <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="account.name" ng-maxlength="50" required />
   <span class="help-inline" ng-show="(submitted || accountForm.name.$dirty) && accountForm.name.$error.maxlength">Name too long</span>
   <span class="help-inline" ng-show="(submitted || accountForm.name.$dirty) && accountForm.name.$error.required">Required</span>
</div>
```

But there seems to be a lot of similar code with only slight differences. What would be the best method of simplifying this to make it a) clearer, b) more maintainable?

**Update 23/07** Doesn't seem like there's an immediate best practice.

Comment: create a method move your logic and call it

Comment: @Atrix1987 ok but how would you implement the method in a DRY way? it needs to be passed the form, field and validation as arguments then call things like myForm.myField.$error.required - I'm not sure how you do that programmatically? Then doesn't that need to go in $rootScope to be reusable? Perhaps a directive would work better.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an error variable in the `$scope` of the controller that controls that template. Something like this:

**html**

```
<div ng-controller="FormCtrl" class="control-group" ng-class="{ error : (submitted || accountForm.name.$dirty) && accountForm.name.$invalid }">
   <label for="name" class="control-label">Company Name:</label>
   <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="account.name" ng-maxlength="50" required />
   <input type="button" ng-click="submitForm()" />
   <span class="help-inline">{{ error }}</span>
</div>
```

**controller**

```
window.FormCtrl = function ($scope) {
    $scope.error = "";

    $scope.submitForm = function() {
        if ($scope.accountForm.name.length > 50) {
            $scope.error = "Name too long";
        }
        else if ($scope.accountForm.name == null || $scope.accountForm.name == undefined) {
            $scope.error = "Name required";
        }
        else {
            $scope.error = "";
            //submit logic
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm not sure this method works when you add lots of additional fields to the form though. I'm also skeptical about duplicating a lot of the logic from the angular validation directives.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to reuse the same code for other form fields, and the validation logic seems to be similar for each of them, i could not find anything with [ngForm](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aform) that would help reuse the code. Rather I would suggest a different approach, where you don't use ngForm and do the validation in js yourself. This way you can reuse the method everywhere.

Here is the link for the jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rCDg8/1/

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
        <form name="accountForm" ng-submit="submit()">
            <div class="control-group" ng-class="class">
                <label for="name" class="control-label">Company Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="account.name" ng-change="validateEntry(account.name)" required></input> 
                <span class="help-inline" ng-show="accountForm.$dirty||accountForm.$invalid">{{msg}}</span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
function DemoCtrl($scope) {

    var longName = 'Name too long';
    var nameRequired = 'Name is required!';
    $scope.class = '';
    $scope.showMsg = false;
    $scope.validateEntry = function (validateItem) {
        if (angular.isDefined(validateItem)) {
            if (validateItem.length > 50) {
                showErrorMsg(longName);
            } else if (validateItem.length === 0) {
                showErrorMsg(nameRequired);
            } else {
                $scope.class = '';
                $scope.showMsg = false;
                $scope.accountForm.$dirty = false;
                $scope.accountForm.$pristine = true;
            }
        } else {
            showErrorMsg(nameRequired);
        }
    };

    $scope.submit = function(){
        alert('IS Form Dirty: '+$scope.accountForm.$dirty);
    };

    function showErrorMsg(msg) {
        $scope.class = 'error';
        $scope.showMsg = true;
        $scope.msg = msg;
        $scope.accountForm.$dirty = true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, not all fields will have the same validation though and most of the clutter I feel is from the logic on the ng-show.